# Questions about distribution-free statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

If I understand correctly, a statistic $T$ is said to be distribution free, if the distribution of $T(X)$ doesn't depend on the distribution of $X$. Examples are [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

To prove $T$ is distribution free, is it equvalent to showing that $T(F^{-1}(U)) = T(U)$, for a random variable $X$ with an arbitrary cdf $F$, and a uniform random variable $U$ over $(0,1)$?

Are distribution free statistics always nonparametric statistics?